# Consume REST API pagination

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, contact, pagination

I am new to the Salesforce/Marketing Cloud APIs and need to consume the Contact API (attribute search) for part of a solution that I am providing a client.  I'm successfully getting expected data returned from my call, but the `page`, `pageSize`, and `count` fields of the returned data structure make it clear that there is the potential for pagination.  The documentation for the request JSON doesn't have anything that stands out to me as being related to pagination, so what is the approach to handling paged data in this API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is documentation under 'Search Contacts', for example, located [in the Marketing Cloud API reference material](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/searchSchema.htm)

You can append the $page to your request URL, for example:

```
www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts/search?$page=2
```

You can return, initially, up to 50 pages with 50 results per page for a max of 2500. But there are ways to continue the request to get more than the initial 2500.

Comment: Currently the default seems to be 2500 per page. Maybe the max per page has been increased in recent years or maybe it varies by resource. I am using /data/v1/customobjectdata/key/EXTERNAL_KEY/rowset and it returns 2500.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a documentation reference, but was able to change the behavior and control the reported page returned by adding a URL parameter named `$page`.  I'd still really appreciate seeing documentation to support this so it doesn't feel like I'm hacking an undocumented feature.